# Prevent return false on children

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, slidetoggle

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('.MobileMenu').click(function() {
        $(".MobileMenu ul.le_menu_level_1").stop().slideToggle(200);
        return false;
    });
});
```

I want to prevent the return false form happening on the child elements. How would I go about making this happen?

Comment: What does your HTML look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check that the clicked element is the same as the one bound in the event handler, and not a click that bubbled up from a child :

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('.MobileMenu').click(function(e) {
        $(".MobileMenu ul.le_menu_level_1").stop().slideToggle(200);
        if (e.target === this) return false;
    });
});
```